# What are the little rounded squares with the x in them for?

Tags: mario-luigi-dream-team

What are the little rounded squares with the x in them for in *Mario & Luigi: Dream Team*? What power/item do I need to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in the series' previous games, x-marks-the-spot icons show where [Beans](http://www.mariowiki.com/Bean) are buried. You need to learn the [Mole Mario](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mole_Mario) move to burrow underground and pop up underneath them, unearthing the bean.

Answer (score 0):

They're Beans. To get them, you need to learn the Mole Mario move, go underground, and dig them up.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was down voted, but perhaps provide supporting links, or explain the mechanic in more detail.